# The Moon's various accelerations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, acceleration

On Wolfram Alpha, the Moon's acceleration is given to be $1.624\ m/s^2$. Isn't the moon gradually spiralling outwards, meaning, isn't its velocity decreasing? Did they just omit the negative sign?

The centripetal acceleration of the moon (once again on Wolfram Alpha) is given to be $1.232×10^{-5}\ m/s^2$. Does this have no relation to the above acceleration?

Finally, using

$$a = \frac{GM_{Earth}}{r^2}$$

Where inputting the radius of Earth in $r$ gives $g$, the acceleration on the surface of the Earth. Dividing the Earth-Moon distance by the Earth's radius (on Wolfram Alpha) we get $58.96$, which I rounded to $60$. Thus, with this being an inverse square law, the acceleration at the distance of the moon should be $1/3600th$ of $g$. However,

$$\frac{9.81}{3600} = 2.7 \cdot 10^{-3}\ m/s^2$$

How does this at all relate to the above two accelerations?

Answer (score 3):

I think they mean the acceleration due to gravity, on the surface of the moon. The moon equivalent of "g" (9.8 m/s²), in other words.

The second value (1.232 * 10^-5) could be the centripetal acceleration on the moon surface due to the rotation on it's own axis.

Answer (score 0):

First, the minus sign is only meant to convey that gravity causes bodies to be pulled toward each-other. In reality, that acceleration has a full direction to it, not just a plus or minus sign.

Second, as @Previous mentioned, you're confusing two different accelerations. The $1.624 \operatorname{m} / \operatorname{s}^2$ is the acceleration the Moon exerts on objects at its surface. The acceleration you calculated is the gravitational acceleration of the Moon by the Earth. The tiny quantity, as @Previous suggested, is what you get when you figure out the centripetal acceleration needed to keep an object moving in a circle that is the size of the moon. This is the decrement in gravitational acceleration from the rotation of the moon at its equator. At other latitudes, the reduction would be smaller. This is because Wolfram Alpha is not correctly understanding the text you're entering.